# Concerns with long-running process on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

**Concerns:**

I have read through posts/blogs that describe IIS could recycle the app pool at any time. Does this mean (in terms of IIS recycling app pool) it would not matter if I make a call to a long running process synchronous or asynchronous, as IIS could recycle the app pool and terminate the long-running process? If this is the case, what are common paths to make sure this does not happen?

**Example**

```
public Task<ActionResult> LongRunningProcessAsync(SubmitFileModel aModel)

    {
        return Task.Run( () => LongRunningProcess( aModel) );
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HostingEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.aspx) has a static method, [RegisterObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.registerobject.aspx), that allows you to place an object in the list of registered objects for the application.

[According to Phil Haack...](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx)

> When ASP.NET tears down the AppDomain, it will first attempt to call
>   Stop method on all registered objects....When ASP.NET calls into this method, your code needs to prevent this method from returning until your work is done.

Alternatively, you could create a service that is not hosted by IIS.

Comment: Right on! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

> If this is the case, what are common paths to make sure this does not happen?

Your application domain will be unloaded on recycling process, with or without using the `RegisterObject` method. It only gives your background work some time to complete (30 seconds by default). If you have long-running job that exceeds this "some time", it will be aborted, and no one will care about automatic retry on restart.

If you want to run long-running jobs in your ASP.NET application, want to keep things simple, and forget about ASP.NET/IIS issues, look at [HangFire](http://hangfire.io) – it uses persistent storages (SQL Server or Redis) and have immunity to the recycling process.